# Is there a lint rule for creating python tuples without bracets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pylint

I want linter to restrict me from using tuple by mistakingly adding a comma at the end of an assignment.

I think that explicitly creating a tuple by using brackets is the only right way to create them.

I have tried 'Pylint' with option '--enable=all', it doesn't warn me of the danger.

```py
# this looks bad and probably was added by mistake
a = 'abc',
# this immediately informs the reader that this is a tuple
#     and for sure was added deliberately
b = ('abc',)
```

I look for a rule for any python linter that would return a warning for the first assignment but not for the second one.

If you have any tips for looking for rules for linters they would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could start [here](http://pylint.pycqa.org/en/stable/how_tos/custom_checkers.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a tool that does that and even more and becomes standard: Black: https://github.com/psf/black.